# Not able to interpret set related statement in FOL

Tags: first-order-logic

I have following facts

1. No set is an element of itself.
2. A set `x` is a subset of a set `y` iff every element of `x` is an
       the element of `y`
3. Something is an element of the union of two sets `x` and `y` iff it
       is an element of `x` or an element of `y`

I have represented the above fact in fol as follows

1. $\forall x \neg Elt(x,x)$
2. $\forall x \forall y \forall z \ Sub(x,y) \equiv (Elt(z,x) \rightarrow
   Elt(z,y))$
3. $\forall x \forall y \forall z \ Elt(z,u(x,y)) \equiv (Elt(z,x) \vee
   Elt(z,y))$

We called the above fact as `T`

As nonlogical symbols, use `Sub(x, y)` to mean "`x` is a subset of `y`," `Elt(e, x)` to mean "`e` is an element of `x`," and `u(x, y)` to mean "the union of `x` and `y`."

I am not able to interpret following statement in FOL.

- Show using logical interpretations that `T` does not entail that the
     union of `x` and `y` is equal to the union of `y` and `x`.
- Let `A` be any set. Show using logical interpretations that `T` entails
     that there is a set `z` such that the union of `A` and `z` is a subset of
     `A`.

Question from Knowledge Representation and Reasoning. To understand Knowledge Representation and Reasoning, I am trying to solve the problem set of that book.

Comment: Your language is mimicking elementary set theory. In it, the equality of sets is defined through the subset relation: $A=B \text { iff } A \subseteq B \land B \subseteq A$.

Comment: In your knowledge Base there is not that information...

Comment: But how to prove fact 1: "not entail" ? Finding a suitable interpretation of the "objects" and predicates that satisfy the theory $T$ and does not satisfy $un(x,y) = un(y,x)$.

Comment: Consider the **wrong** example: domain $\mathbb N$ and interpret $El$ with $<$. Clearly: $\forall n \lnot (n < n)$ and thus the first axiom is satisfied. This is the way to interpret the theory.

Comment: $un$ is a function symbol: $un(x,y)$ denotes an object of the domain. In order to find the suitable interpretation, we have to think at non-symmetrical operations. Arithmetical ops like $x+y$ and $xy$ are symmetrical; thus, they will not do.

Comment: thanks a lot information is really useful